# Arcgis API for Javascript 4 Calcite map add feature layer

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

I am new to the ArcGIS API for Javscript 4.0 API. Using the calcite sample on the API website. Where can I add in a feature Layer to the map view and scene view? Essentially I'm trying to merge the Feature layer sample 
here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-featurelayer/index.html

```
/********************
     * Add feature layer
     ********************/

    // Carbon storage of trees in Warren Wilson College.
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0"
    });

    map.add(featureLayer);
```

with the calcite map sample here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/frameworks-bootstrap/index.html

but am not sure what part to add the layers to. I have tried a few times. See below. Thanks

```
      /******************************************************************
   *
   * Create the map and scene view and ui components
   * 
   ******************************************************************/

  // Map
  var map = new Map({
    basemap: app.basemap
  });
  app.mapView = new MapView({
    container: "mapViewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: app.center,
    scale: app.scale,
    padding: app.viewPadding,
    popup: new Popup({
      dockOptions: app.dockOptions
    }),
    ui: {
      components: app.uiComponents
    }
  });

  // Scene
  var mapScene = new Map({
    basemap: app.basemap,
    ground: "world-elevation"
  });
  app.sceneView = new SceneView({
    container: "sceneViewDiv",
    map: mapScene,
    center: app.center,
    scale: app.scale,
    padding: app.viewPadding,
    popup: new Popup({
      dockOptions: app.dockOptions
    }),
    ui: {
      components: app.uiComponents
    }
  });

  // Set the active view to scene
  app.activeView = app.mapView;

  // Create the search widget and add it to the navbar instead of view
  app.searchWidget = new Search({
    view: app.activeView
  }, "searchWidgetDiv");
  app.searchWidget.startup();

  // IS THIS WHERE I CAN ADD LAYERS??????????????????
  var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Landscape_Trees/FeatureServer/0"
    });

  app.mapView.map.add(featureLayer);
  app.sceneView.map.add(featureLayer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them directly to the map object in 4.0.  Look at the API documentation here for a small example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Map.html#layers.

Essentially it would look something like this:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(url);
var map = new Map({
  basemap: app.basemap,
  layers: [featureLayer]
});
```

You would need to make sure you apply this to whichever map you want them to render on.

Comment: If there is something incorrect with this post, please inform as to what it is or provide the correct answer so that this can be updated for the benefit of the community

Answer (score 0):

you may need the following code:

```
  var countyLayer = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:6080/arcgis/rest/services/newyourk/MapServer/1"
  });
  app.map.add(countyLayer);
```